# boost spirit qi multiple start rules

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

How can I define a spirit qi grammar which can have more than one starting rule?
I am working on an XML grammar and I want to have 4 possible starting rules.

So if I have a grammar called `xml_grammar` and the base_type is `(A, "A")`. I also want few other starting rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All formal grammars have a single start symbol. If you have multiple start symbols under consideration (say A, B, C and D), you can convert them into a single artificial start symbol S with a rule like:

```
S = A | B | C | D
```

Comment: Thanks thiton. It looks helpfuf but I am not sure will it work or not. I am trying to do this and test it for an iso_8859 xml grammar. Will let you know if it works and will accept the answer.